# I said something terrible at the workplace, again. Am I gone?

Tags: human-resources, stress, inappropriate-content

So I said something inappropriate a year ago to one of the work girls about how I wanted to get with her friend and she dobbed me in and I got a warning from HR. I've been good since except ...

Now I said the N word by accident today and one of my African coworkers was nearby. I apologised immediately and she said it was okay. But I'm scared. One witness was there and he knows it was an accident but is very close friends with my manager.

Am I screwed?
Should I confess to HR directly now? 
What should I do? I'm so scared! It was an accident.

Comment: This can't be a real question, surely.  This has got to be some sort of satire.

Comment: How are we supposed to tell you how "screwed" you are when we neither know your superiors nor your co-workers?

Comment: "by accident" ???

Comment: Also note that if she is African (Not American) the word might not even be offensive to her. Other way also true, People with lighter skin colors might also get offended by the use of the word. Regardless the word should not be used in most cases. If your profession requires you to talk about it, then do not be cowered to do so. However thread carefully howeverit does not seem to be the case for you. So no do not report yourself, you said something that MIGHT offend somone. You do not know if you actually did.

Comment: Please don't refer to female colleagues as "work girls."

Comment: If I was you I would move to a monestary and take a vow of Silence...

Answer (score 10):

You've apologised, she accepted.

It was a bad thing to do, but just wait to see if there's any outcome - you don't have to go to HR to self-report.  Just deal with any outcome in a mature and contrite fashion.

And watch yourself in future, it's good to get into the habit of omitting potentially offensive terms/words in your every-day speech.

Comment: But if the word is going to get out, is it better that I confess first?

Comment: Your choice.  If you self-report to HR, they're more than likely to act.  If you don't, then it depends on whether anyone else reports you to HR.

Answer (score 8):

First off, just don't use that word.

Second, you need to work on your work-mode. When you're with work people, focus on the work, office-safe topics of conversation (immagine you're surrounded by kids).

As for what to do in the immediate aftermath... Do nothing. You've apologised already. If your colleague escalates, be apologetic some more. Otherwise, just work on your big mouth :D

Comment: "First off, just don't use that word." Under no circumstances is this word ever appropriate. Remove it from your vocabulary. Don't use it in private, don't use it on social media (that can get you fired too!), don't use it anywhere ever again.

Answer (score 1):

First, I find it great you realised by yourself you said something offensive and apologised instead of making excuses.

I know the problem myself of using unacceptable words because I learned them as a child as being neutral, only to find out as an adult they are not.

What is helping me to banish the n word of my active vocabulary is to get used to say "black" or "black person" (or in my case the equivalent in German) instead of N*****. Maybe you want to try to not to make any distinction while speaking based on the skin colour. It feels odd first, but it works.

Comment: You might want to elaborate a little on why it might seem odd to not make a skin-color distinction while speaking.

Comment: @brhans Sure. I realised that when explaining about what did/said someone, if this someone was black or asian-looking, I would say "a black/Asian guy told me x or did you", instead of "someone told bla". Since this is usually unimportant information, and I was distinguishing by skin colour or eye form, I decided to still say "someone" when talking about a black/Asian person. At the beginning I wasn't used to that, so it felt odd to me.